# What is the name of the module that gives a detailed report of modules and themes installed?

Tags: 7

There is a module that gives a very detailed view of all the modules and themes installed on a site and the core modules as well. I can't remember the name, but I know it exists because I installed it for testing purposes some time ago.

Can anyone remember the name, or tell me about some other modules which do the same thing so I can check if it is the one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module in question is the [Views System](http://drupal.org/project/views_system) module.

It provides a very detailed view of all the modules and themes on your system. It was actually installed on one of my systems.

The name makes it sound as though it is a Views enhancing module rather than the fact that it relies uses Views to generate its output.

System View may be the better name.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are talking about the [Module summary](http://drupal.org/project/module_summary) module for D7. The [Used modules](http://drupal.org/project/used_modules) for D6 is no longer supported.

Comment: I tried this one which is also informative, but it is not the one. I think the name of that one starts with 'P'

Comment: It turns out the name of the module does not being with a 'P'. One of the same class of modules, Profiler, http://drupal.org/project/profiler is probably what I had in mind.